# jQuery conflicts with Scriptaculous

Tags: jquery, scriptaculous, conflict

WHY is it that i cannot use Scriptaculous and jQuery in the same page without calling:
    jQuery.noConflict() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because they both use the `$` variable in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $ in the following scenario:

```
<script>
 jQuery.noConflict();

 // Put all your code in your document ready area
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // Do jQuery stuff using $
   $("div").hide();
 });

 // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
 $('someid').hide();
</script>
```

I think it's the best way of using libraries which had the same $ function

Answer (score 0):

> WHY is it that i cannot use
>   Scriptaculous and jQuery in the same
>   page without calling:
>   jQuery.noConflict() ?

If you were able to use different javascript libraries on same page, the very existence of `jQuery.noConflict()` was not needed. It is because of special symbol `$` which holds special meaning in those different javascript libraries.